# Passing id from one combobox to populate second combo box in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

How do I pass the categoryId for the selected CategoryName in the first combo box, which would populate the products in the second combo box /

the table structure is a below.

Table_Category
CategoryId
CategoryyName

Table_Product
ProductId
ProductName
CategoryId
ProductPrice
ProductUnit

Thanks, 
Hussain Patel

Comment: And what is the question? You're doing it right : "*pass the categoryId to the database,which would be the relevant products for the specific category id and populate the second combo box*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first combo box (cmbcategory) using ADO.NET (code), get category object (containing the categoryId and categoryName) and bind to itemsource property of first combo box (cmbcategory)

Example
  cmbcategory.ItemsSource = categories.DefaultView;

In the xaml code for the cmbcategory add two attributes DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath. assign the the "CategoryName" and "CategoryID" to them.
Example

Now you can retrieve the category id for the item selected in the cmbcategory,as below 
  string tmp = cmbcategory.SelectedValue.ToString();

This can be passed to the ADO.NET SQL command object and products can be retrieved and the bindded to the  cmbproduct combo box as below

cmbproduct.ItemsSource = products.DefaultView;

Thus for each category selected in the first cmbcategory the products are populated in the cmbproducts.

Thanks,
hussain