# Binding a set of lists to a combobox from another list of objects which contain the lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, compositecollection

For simplicity sake, I am going to use the idea of a "car make" and a "car model" to explain my problem.  I have a list of car make objects and each car make has its own list of car models.  I need to populate a combo box which contains a list of all car models.  I have researched this and believe that a CompositeCollection is the way to go, however, I can't seem to figure out how to do this when I don't know how large my CarMake list will be.  With a fixed-length CarMake list I can do the following but I need it to be dynamic.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="carSelectComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CarMake0Collection" 
                              Source="{Binding CarMakes[0].Models}"  />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CarMake1Collection" 
                              Source="{Binding CarMakes[1].Models}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
         <CompositeCollection>
             <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CarMake0Collection}}" />
             <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CarMake1Collection}}" />
         </CompositeCollection>
     </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
 </ComboBox>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Also, there is a chance (even a likelihood) that the list of car makes, as well as the car models, may grow/change while running the application.

Comment: Try below link for answer this might help ..
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495422/passing-id-from-one-combobox-to-populate-second-combo-box-in-wpf>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for converter, unless you have good reason not to.

```
public class CarMakeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = (List<CarMakes>)value;
        return input.SelectMany(carMake=> carMake.Models);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And later being used in your `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="carSelectComboBox"
 ItemsSource="{Binding CarMakes, Converter={StaticResource converter}"
 DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This definitely solved the problem.  You're my hero!